# How to check which ASP.NET Version was used for .aspx files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I've got an old website which I have to recreate in PHP instead of ASP. The website was written in ASP.NET (.aspx files), and in order to display the website I have to state which ASP.NET version was used. Can I get that information out of the .aspx files?

Thanks.

EDIT: This is inside my webconfig file:

```
<compilation debug="false">
   <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31CF2543AD364E11"/>
   </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: Do you have Visual studio and `csproj` file? then you can open the project from visual studio and run it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the original Visual Studio project there should be a project file or files depending on the number of projects. The file is something like `ProjectName.csproj` (which is just an XML file). Open it with your preferred text editor and look for the following line which will indicate which version of the framework that was used for that specific project.

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Based on your updated question it appears as though it is .NET 1.0

Comment: I have just something like `<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">` or `<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` but nothing with `TargetFrameworkVersion`...

Comment: Could you show us what is inside the `<compilation><assemblies>.....</compilation></assemblies>` section of the `Web.config` file? This will probably help us identity the framework version used.

Comment: I doubt it's .NET 1.0. The MSBuild project file format wasn't introduced until .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to go to Properties in top ribbon and then [ProjectName]Properties. This will show you the framework clearly

Comment: You had better to be a more explanatory. In which program properties will be clicked.